Как можно оптимизировать запрос Laravel?
Имеются 3 таблицы со связью: Test1, Test2, Test3. В них примитивные данные, поля "name" и "desc". Связаны один ко многим: Test1(id)->Test2(test2_id), Test2(id)->Test3(test3_id).
Выгружаю данные из них по связи hasMany вот так:
public function method1()
{
 return $this->hasMany(Test2::class, 'test2_id', 'id')->with('method2');
}

Метод 2 вот такой:
public function method2(){
      return $this->hasMany(Test3::class, 'test3_id', 'id');
    }

У меня всё вытягивается, даже запросов не так уж много, но много памяти выделяется, т.е. дебагер показывает большое количество обращений к моделям, хотя там всего порядка 10 записей... Добавляю записи количество моделей увеличивается в запросе.
Подскажите, как можно оптимизировать запрос? Желательно через Eloquent.

пожалуйста напишите, все связи, и как вы делаете запрос, при котором у вас такой результат
